# when using dbms_metadata.get_ddl to generate the ddl for a table can I exclude creating of constraints

Tags: oracle, ddl

I am trying to develop some scripts so I can recreate the oracle schema for a development user when I need to refresh the data from a MySQL production database.

I am using the dbms_metadata.get_ddl function to generate the ddl, but it also creates all the constraints for the tables and I need to wait on creating at least the foreign constraints since I want to load the actual data first.

Is there a way to tell dbms_metadata.get_ddl to not create the indexes and constraints?

Comment: This is answered here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62734/how-to-generate-create-table-script-without-primary-and-foreign-key-in-oracle

Comment: You could also disable the FK constraints, load the data, then re-enable them.